# css guide for centering a div over 2 divs

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I am a beginner in CSS(Not able to position HTML elements properly) and I am creating a login form for the angular app, I am using material design.

I want to create login page as follows,
[image]

In my App, I have the following code,

```
<div class="firstDiv"></div>
<div class="secondDiv"></div>
<div class="loginDiv">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Input">
  </mat-form-field>
  <br/>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Textarea">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

> NOTE: I will modify the details for login as required in sample login
>   image as above.

CSS file is as follows,

```
.firstDiv {
    height: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: orangered;
    display: inline-block;
}

.secondDiv {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color:whitesmoke;
    display: inline-block;
}

.loginDiv {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: black;
    background-color:white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

I am not able to get the form as required and also if the screen size is reduced the login form does not fit according to the screen size and login details get messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #ddd;
  background-color: #23bdf5;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #34b9f7 0%, #34b9f7 40%, #f0f0f0 40%, #f0f0f0 100%);
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

.center-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 50px;
  right: 50px;
}

.form-element {
  height: 50vh;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <div class="center-content">
    <div class="form-element">
      this is where your form would go
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works by doing the following:

First I create a `.container` element for the page and added a [linear gradient](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-linear-gradient/) background to it; I used a linear-gradient generator you can find one simply by googling. Next I set the height of the container element to be 100vh which is 100% the height of the browser window; [You can read about viewport units here](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/).

Within the container I create an `.center-content` element to position the content to be **vertically** centred within the `.container` element and always 50px from the edge of the container regardless of the screen size, you can change this value to whatever suits your needs.

In this example I've set the element that would contain the form to 50vh just show you what it would look like, but for you can remove this and add content inside the element and then add padding to define it's dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I got the required alignment with the following changes in CSS for loginDiv,

```
.loginDiv {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: yellow;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 28%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use font awesome icon in material angular also

```
 <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```